# Dockers\Nexus: Incorrect username or password, or no permission to use the application?

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype

Firstly, I'm new to dockers. I have installed sonatype/nexus3 using docker command and pulled successfully and I'm able to run it locally. But when I'm trying to sign in with
username: admin
password: admin123
it throws the below error.

Incorrect username or password, or no permission to use the application.

I'm following this [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploying-private-npm-packages-to-nexus-a16722cc8166)

Answer (score 0):

By default the initial admin password is randomly generated. You can find it in the /nexus-data/admin.password file.  If you want to suppress that behavior you can add “-Dnexus.security.randompassword=false” to the INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAM environment variable when starting up the container.  Be sure to add to it, don’t replace all the defaults.

https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3#notes

Answer (score 0):

Initially, the admin password is generated inside the Nexus container and stored in the file 'sonatype-work/nexus3/admin.password'. you can access the container using the following command:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/sh
```

Once inside the container, run the following command to display the admin password:

```
cat sonatype-work/nexus3/admin.password
```